# Coding Error - Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Cant figure out what is wrong with my code. Please help.

Errors:

Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 3, Line 120 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method rad2deg.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 3, Line 121 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method rad2deg.
Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 3, Line 129 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method rad2deg.

Code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var missile:Array = new Array();
var timer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addMissile);
timer.start();

plane.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveObjects);

function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        plane.y -= 8;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        plane.y += 8;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        plane.x -= 8;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        plane.x += 8;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function addMissile(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    var missile:Missile = new Missile();
    var side:Number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
    if (side == 1) {
        missile.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        missile.y = - missile.height;
    } else if (side == 2) {
        missile.x = stage.stageWidth + missile.width;
        missile.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    } else if (side == 3) {
        missile.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
        missile.y = stage.stageHeight + missile.height;
    } else if (side == 4) {
        missile.x = - missile.width
        missile.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    }
    missile.angle = getAngle(missile.x, missile.y, plane.x, plane.y);
    missile.speed = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 15);
    addChild(missile);
    missile.push(missile);
}

function moveObjects(evt:Event):void {
    moveMissile();
}

function moveMissile():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < missile.length; i++) {
        var dx = Math.cos(rad2deg(missile[i].angle)) * missile[i].speed;
        var dy = Math.sin(rad2deg(missile[i].angle)) * missile[i].speed;
        missile[i].x += dx;
        missile[i].y += dy;
    }
}

function getAngle(x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number {
    var radians:Number = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
    return rad2deg(radians);
}
```

Comment: Either add the function rad2deg or stop calling it...?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the answer.  try adding this to your code:

```
deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
rad2deg = 180/Math.PI;
```

Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've defined a function `rad2deg()`?

Add this somewhere:

```
function rad2deg(radians:Number):Number
{
    return radians * 180 / Math.PI;
}
```

Important to note is that the only place you'll find degrees useful in Flash is setting the [`rotation`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#rotation) of a `DisplayObject`.

This line from your code for example won't work as expected - `Math.cos()` and so on need radians.

```
Math.cos(rad2deg(missile[i].angle))
```